# Datagrid extends off window

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

Hey everyone. I have a problem with a datagrid in my window. I want it to extend only to its needed size if it doesn't fill the entire window or show a scroll bar if it does take up the entire screen. Here's my xaml

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Name="dg">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col1"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col1"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>            
    </DataGrid>

    <GroupBox Grid.Row="2" Margin="5">
        <Button>Click</Button>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

If I set the row height for the datagrid to * it extends the datagrid's gray background down the entire row. But if I set the height to auto, then it won't show a scrollbar when there are too many items for the window.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried nesting the DataGrid in a [ScrollViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't give the desired result either. It will still extend off the screen with RowHeight=auto and behaves very similar to just a datagrid if RowHeight=*

Comment: After some more messing around, if I nested the data grid inside a scrollviewer and a stackpanel, I got the results I wanted. Can you put that in your answer for others?

Comment: Based on what I posted below, I'm not even sure that you need a scrollviewer at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be elsewhere.  I tried your code locally and created some data.  See below:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ControlSandbox.StackOverflowQuestion"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid x:Name="Root">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Name="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col1" Binding="{Binding Item1}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col1" Binding="{Binding Item2}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>

    <GroupBox Grid.Row="2" Margin="5">
        <Button>Click</Button>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

I created some data like so:

```
public partial class StackOverflowQuestion : UserControl
{
    public StackOverflowQuestion()
    {
        Data = new ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, string>>();
        Data.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("test", "test"));
        Data.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("test", "test"));
        Data.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("test", "test"));
        Data.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("test", "test"));
        Data.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("test", "test"));
        Data.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("test", "test"));
        Data.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("test", "test"));
        Data.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("test", "test"));
        Data.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("test", "test"));
        Data.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("test", "test"));
        Data.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("test", "test"));
        Data.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("test", "test"));

        InitializeComponent();

        Root.DataContext = this;


    }

    public ObservableCollection<Tuple<String, String>> Data {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

The result is a properly scrollbar-ed control:

[image]

And in the other direction:

[image]

Unless I'm completely misunderstanding your question?

UPDATE:  Added full screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Try having not enough items to fill the screen and tell me if you see the background of the datagrid or the background of the window.

Comment: Updated with the full screen shot.

Comment: Yes, that is the same problem I was having. The gray background of the data grid was covering up the background of the window that I wanted to see until the datagrid had enough items in it to actually fill the screen. I would have set the background of the dg to transparent, but our datagrids have a shadow around the border. This created a random shadow surrounding the invisible background